# Select data by status column in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

IN Custom php code

```
$select_query = "select * from admin where Stutes = '1' order by ID asc";
```

How we can embed this code in my this laravel 5 code

```
public function index()
{   
    $books=Book::all();
    return view('books.index', compact('books'));
}
```

Comment: check laravel query builder http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Query builder

```
$admin= DB::tabe('admin')
->select("*")
->where("Stautes",1)
->orderBy("ID", "asc")
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

### In controller

```
public function index()
{   
    //$books=Book::all();
    $books= DB::table('books')
    ->select('*')
    ->where('status', '1')
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get();
    return view('books.index', compact('books'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Optimised Query:**

Since you are trying to **retrieve all rows** your query can be likewise:

```
$admin= DB::table('admin')->where("Status",1) ->orderBy("ID", "asc") ->get();
```

If you want to **retrieve a specific column**:

```
$admin_ids = DB::table('admin')->select('id')->where("Status",1) ->orderBy("ID", "asc") ->get();
```

[Laravel Select docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#selects)

Hope this helpful.